# How to append value to an array keeping old value intact in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Google visualization API requires arrays like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
         ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'],            // RGB value
         ['Copper', 10.49, 'silver'],            // English color name
         ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
         ['Gold', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ], // CSS-style declaration
      ]);
```

I have separately array of columns

```
var columns = ['Copper', 'Copper', 'Gold', 'Gold'];
```

for values

```
var values = [8.94, 10.49, 19.30, 21.45];
```

and for colors

```
var styles = ['#b87333', 'silver', 'gold', 'color: #e5e4e2'];
```

Am I really in need to write multilevel loop with multiple conditions to build this array? Or there are simpler ways?

I can't `push` because arrays should be intact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Array#map`.

```js
var columns = ['Copper', 'Copper', 'Gold', 'Gold'],
    values = [8.94, 10.49, 19.30, 21.45],
    styles = ['#b87333', 'silver', 'gold', 'color: #e5e4e2'],
    res = columns.map((v,i) => [v, values[i], styles[i]]),
    result = [['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }], ...res];
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just need to immutably copy the array and then do whatever you want with it. Try this:

```
// ES6
var myArr = [1, 2, 3]
var newArr = [ ...myArr ]

// ES5
var myArr = [1, 2, 3];
var newArr = [].concat(myArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map them together, here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qt0s5a4e/)

```
var columns = ['Copper', 'Copper', 'Gold', 'Gold'];
var values = [8.94, 10.49, 19.30, 21.45];
var styles = ['#b87333', 'silver', 'gold', 'color: #e5e4e2'];

var newArr = columns.map((item, index) => {return [columns[index], values[index], styles[index]]})

console.log(newArr) //=> ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'],
                    //['Copper', 10.49, 'silver'],
                    //['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
                    //['Gold', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ],
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 solution using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function

```js
var columns = ['Copper', 'Copper', 'Gold', 'Gold'];
var values = [8.94, 10.49, 19.30, 21.45];
var styles = ['#b87333', 'silver', 'gold', 'color: #e5e4e2'];

// Reduce all arrays to one vlaue
var result  = columns.reduce((acc, init, i) => {
    acc.push([init, values[i], styles[i]])
    return acc
}, [])


var out = [
         ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
         ...result
      ]

console.log(out)
```